Using 2x4 active decoder and a NOR gate design a XOR gate
I am trying to create a  a XOR gate. only from  2x4 and NOR Gates. however I am stuck. Please draw the diagram or give image of this.

Just nor the two decoder outputs where xor should return false. Anyway I'm not sure this type of question is on-topic for SO.
